# Getting the collection in a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, what I am trying to do is create a bbcode editor with a textbox, some buttons and jQuery.  Here is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn glyphicon bbcode" rel="bold"><b>B</b></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn glyphicon bbcode" rel="italic"><i>I</i></button>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="bbcode" rel="editor" cols="100" rows="12"></textarea>
</div>
```

and my plugin is called using:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('.bbcode').bbcode();
    });
</script>
```

and the plugin itself, I am just trying to get the basics done at the minute to update the textbox data when a button is clicked:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.bbcode = function() {

        this.click(function() {
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
            if (rel == 'editor') {
                return this;
            } else {
                alert($(this).attr('rel'));  // I can see this pop up so the click event is firing
                $('.bbcode[rel=editor]').val('test');
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
} (jQuery));
```

This seems to be the only way I can pick up the textbox, I don't really want to hardcode the class I want like that.  I think what I am looking for is a way to get the collection from the function call in the script tags.

This is more than likely something stupid/obvious I have overlooked.

Comment: What do you mean by "the collection?"

Comment: Do you want `$(this).find("[rel=editor]").val("test")`?

Comment: In this example, its the collection is the DOM elements returned by $('.bbcode'), perhaps this is the wrong term for it?

Comment: @soktinpk that didn't work, I think `$(this)` is the element I have actually clicked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` in the immediate function refers to the collection. However, it is shadowed by the `this` inside your click handler (which refers to the element being clicked) so you cannot access it.

Create a variable to store `this` and that'll be your collection.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.bbcode = function () {
        var $editors = this;
        this.click(function () {
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
            if (rel == 'editor') {
                return this;
            } else {
                alert($(this).attr('rel')); // I can see this pop up so the click event is firing
                $editors.val('test');
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```